# Why is the 1st central moment equal to 0?

Tags: random-variable, moments

I was studying about random variables when I came across the topics "Central Moments"
Following the formula given for nth central moment on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment#cite_note-ProbRand-1, can anyone explain why the 1st central moment is taken to be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th central moment is defined as $E[(X-E(X))^n]$, so for $n=1$, we have $E[(X-E(X))]$. By linearity of expectation, this equals $E(X)-E[E(X)]$. Since $E(X)$ already is a constant, so that $E[E(X)]=E(X)$.